# Any way to write the Terminal scrollback history?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I would like to open a new tab in Terminal with custom scrollback history. The primary use-case is to "fork" an existing tab such that both tabs contain the same scrollback history, but more generally I would like to have some custom scripts save and restore Terminal sessions.

I know about the history restore functionality already in Terminal but it doesn't suit my needs; the main one being that I have a system built around the `script` command and some `zsh` hooks to save history and output for all terminal sessions for later auditing purposes (recalling changes that I've made).

I would now like to switch to use `osascript` to save the history and on restoring sessions later to match up the new session with its prior one- in a way, implementing long-term, persistent sessions. I've had Terminal's saved sessions lose their data too many times that I am working around it.

Comment: There's no way to detach and reattach screen to suit your needs?

Comment: I can’t quite tell if this is brilliant or ridiculous. I wonder if `screen` and `tmux` would be better suited to manage shell history buffers?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps use iterm? http://www.iterm2.com

Its free and should fit your needs?

Comment: If you wanted to go so far as to state that this will absolutely 100% solve the problem - that would be a fine answer by saying to pick another package, but if there is doubt to whether another software package works, that would be best as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: from what i can ascertain iTerm does NO "restoration" of the scrollback history... which sucks cause it's a nice feature of the otherwise pretty lame Apple `Terminal.app`